# How to determine whether the cursor is inside a gtk.Menu?

Tags: python, menu, position, pygtk, dimensions

I have a `gtk.Menu` (which is being used as a popup) and I need to determine whether the mouse cursor is inside the confines of the menu.

I can get the mouse's position on the screen using [this method](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq23.024.htp). But how do I get the dimensions and position of the menu after calling `menu.popup(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I didn't look close enough at some of the methods that `gtk.Menu` provides.

It turns out that `gtk.Menu` is a descendant of `gtk.Widget` which has a method `get_window` which returns the menu's underlying `gtk.gdk.Window`.

From there, it's simply a matter of calling `get_frame_extents()` which returns a `gtk.gdk.Rectangle` with the position and size of the menu.